# What is the meaning of the word "sharp" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, synonyms

This is a context from [an English translation](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/182/crime-and-punishment/3400/part-2-chapter-2/) of "Crime And Punishment" by Dostoevsky

"In the passage the idea had occurred to him to
keep on his overcoat and walk away, and so give the two
ladies a **sharp** and emphatic lesson and make them feel the
gravity of the position."

The only answer i could find about this expression was on HiNative forum. One of the users said: ""**sharp**" can be used as an **adverb** - meaning precise, sudden or abrupt. It's not commonly used in this expression in the U.S., but the person who posted may be from the U.K."

But this answer isn't satisfactory to me as "sudden" and "abrupt" are adjectives(TFD source below)
5. sudden, marked, abrupt, extreme, distinct *There's been a **sharp** rise in the rate of inflation.*

Can anyone explain what **sharp** means in this context and what part of speech it is as well as give a suitable synonym for it? TomHanks eghr...I mean thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3):

It is an adjective modifying the noun "lesson".

Yes: "precise", "sudden", or "abrupt" all are good synonyms for "sharp" here.  I would say this is indeed used in the United States to some extent.

To me it also connotes *cutting* or *piercing*, almost as a metaphor, in the sense that the lesson may be a bit painful, harsh, or difficult to accept.